# How to count multiple joined rows in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, join

I have 4 tables: A, B, C, D.

- Table B has a foreign key to A
- Table C has a foreign key to A
- Table D has a foreign key to C
  [image]

What I can query so far:

- I know how to select all rows from A and count amount of joined rows of B.
- I know how to select all rows from A and count amount of joined rows from D (via C).

Now I want to merge those two queries in one select and show there count_b and count_d. But the resulting select shows wrong count. Here's how I do it:

```
SELECT
  "A"."id",
  COUNT("B"."id") AS "B_count",
  COUNT("D"."id") AS "D_count"
FROM "users" AS "A" LEFT OUTER JOIN "B" AS "B"
    ON "A"."id" = "B"."a__id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "C" AS "C"
    ON "A"."id" = "C"."a_id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "D" AS "D"
    ON "C"."id" = "D"."c_id"
GROUP BY "A"."id"
```

There's probably the issue with `GROUP BY`. IT seems I need to write separate group by for each count. I'm looking for result without nested selects (because I still need to map this to ORM, dont ask why). Is it possible to archive with `distinct by`?

Comment: try with count(distinct D) and count(distinct B)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Due you are joining 3 tables, you should use DISTINCT within COUNT:

```
SELECT
  "A"."id",
  COUNT(DISTINCT "B"."id") AS "B_count",
  COUNT(DISTINCT "D"."id") AS "D_count"
FROM "users" AS "A" LEFT OUTER JOIN "B" AS "B"
    ON "A"."id" = "B"."a__id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "C" AS "C"
    ON "A"."id" = "C"."a_id"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "D" AS "D"
    ON "C"."id" = "D"."c_id"
GROUP BY "A"."id"
```

Comment: The DISTINCT was what I was missing :-)